# How to pass a list of lists to tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to build a model in tensorflow that uses sentences in order to predict images. I transformed all the sentences to a list of lists of size 300 each one.

```
0        [-0.22607538080774248, 0.30380163341760635, 0....
1        [-0.10856867488473654, 0.17990960367023945, 0....
2        [-0.15721752890385687, 0.1608753204345703, 0.4...
3        [-0.12894394318573177, 0.13585415855050087, 0....
4        [-0.27382510248571634, 0.22385768964886665, 0....

40449    [-0.28715573996305466, 0.2722414545714855, 0.6...
40451    [-0.04035807272884995, 0.2275269404053688, 0.3...
40452    [-0.19741788890678436, 0.3378600552678108, 0.7...
40453    [-0.10771899553947151, 0.13040382787585258, 0....
40454    [-0.07718773453962058, 0.28313175216317177, 0....
Name: Text, Length: 31978, dtype: object
```

How can I give it to tensorflow as an input?

I tried

```
model = Sequential([
Dense(2, activation="relu", input_shape = (300,)), 
Reshape((256, 256, 3), input_shape = (300,))
])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit(x_ent, y_ent, epochs=3, batch_size=64)
```

But when I compile the model, it says

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_2_input to have shape (300,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Also, I used the Reshape layer in order to transform vectors to images, but I don't know if there is a better way to do that.

Comment: Since I have to use the sentences as features, I tried to get a vector representation of them and give those vectors as an input for the first layer of the model and then set a layer that gets arrays of shape (256, 256, 3) to predict images.

Comment: Why do you need this (256, 256, 3) exact shape? Is it supposed to be the shape of the image you are trying to predict? Are you trying to construct images out of sentences or are you trying to classify images? What exactly do you mean by predict?

Comment: It is an assignment for school, and due to hardware limitations the original pictures were rescaled to 256x256 for the calculations to be faster. And yes, I want to construct images out of sentences.

Comment: What will be the models input? Images or sentence vectors? If you need to pass list of sentence vectors to the model I have provided an answer. If you need to pass images you should totally change input_shape as input_shape = (amount_of_pictures,256, 256, 3). Are you trying to implement something like this? https://github.com/aelnouby/Text-to-Image-Synthesis

Comment: The input are sentence vectors. I tried to use the Input layer and added Input(shape=(x_ent.shape[0], 300)), 
where  x_ent.shape[0] is the number of sentences, but when I run it, it gets this error:
Error when checking input: expected input_6 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (31978, 1)

Comment: Are you defining layer like this Sequential([Dense(2, activation="relu", input_shape = (x_ent.shape[0],30 0))]) or are you still trying to use reshape?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214285/discussion-between-alfie-gonzalez-and-meto).

Answer (score 0):

Does each image need 300 sentences for classification? Or does each sentence has a feature vector of size 300? If you have each sentence as a list which has a lenght of 300 and if you have 40454 sentences your input shape must be 40454x300. So you could pass `input_shape = (40454,300)` to Dense input layer. It should work.

I referred to the [tensorflow keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense).

> N-D tensor with shape: (batch_size, ..., input_dim). The most common
>   situation would be a 2D input with shape (batch_size, input_dim).